# Unsure of why the StopIteration isn't handled by "yield from"

Tags: python, generator, coroutine, yield-from

Looking at the following sample code from the "Fluent Python" book that explains the "bidirectional tunnel" functionality of `yield from`, I have the following question.

```py
from collections import namedtuple

Result = namedtuple('Result', 'count average')


# the subgenerator
def averager():  # <1>
    total = 0.0
    count = 0
    average = None
    while True:
        term = yield  # <2>
        if term is None:  # <3>
            break
        total += term
        count += 1
        average = total/count
    return Result(count, average)  # <4>


# the delegating generator
def grouper(results, key):  # <5>
    while True:  # <6>
        results[key] = yield from averager()  # <7>


# the client code, a.k.a. the caller
def main(data):  # <8>
    results = {}
    for key, values in data.items():
        group = grouper(results, key)  # <9>
        next(group)  # <10>
        for value in values:
            group.send(value)  # <11>
        group.send(None)  # important! <12>
        print("wrapped up grouper")
    print(results)


data = {
    'girls;kg':
        [40.9, 38.5, 44.3, 42.2, 45.2, 41.7, 44.5, 38.0, 40.6, 44.5],
    'girls;m':
        [1.6, 1.51, 1.4, 1.3, 1.41, 1.39, 1.33, 1.46, 1.45, 1.43],
    'boys;kg':
        [39.0, 40.8, 43.2, 40.8, 43.1, 38.6, 41.4, 40.6, 36.3],
    'boys;m':
        [1.38, 1.5, 1.32, 1.25, 1.37, 1.48, 1.25, 1.49, 1.46],
}
```

Why do I get a `StopIteration` exception when I replace the delegating generator above with the following delegating generator?

```py
def grouper(results, key):
    results[key] = yield from averager()
```

From what I have learned so far, it seems in theory that removing the `while True` should be fine. `group.send(None)` would cause the `averager()` coroutine to `break` and return the `Result(...)`, which would be passed up to the delegating generator. And then the delegating generator would finish by assigning that `Result(...)` to `results[key]`.

But what's happening instead is the following.

```
Traceback (mostrecent call last):
  File "coroaverager3.py", line 111, in <module>
    main(data)
  File "coroaverager3.py", line 83, in main
    group.send(None)  # important! <12>
StopIteration
```

Any insight?

Comment: After I looked up this: [pep-380#formal-semantics](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0380/#formal-semantics), It confused me again. It seems that before the assignment of `results[key]`, the `StopIteration` has been handled.

Comment: I think
    def grouper(results, key):
        results[key] = yield from averager()
is right and shall raises StopIteration when averager has finished.
From "https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0380/"
- return expr in a generator causes StopIteration(expr) to be raised upon exit from the generator.
A delegating generator is still a generator and expected to raise StopIteration when exiting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You’re right that the delegating generator assigns to `results[key]`, but it doesn’t *finish* by doing that.  Its execution continues, since there’s nowhere for it to suspend.  Of course, it immediately falls off the end, causing the `send(None)` to raise `StopIteration` (since there’s no *value* (from a `yield`) for it to return).

The `while True:` is a sort of silly way of adding another place to suspend; a single extra `yield` after the `yield from` would be a bit more obvious.  (It could provide a value distinct from those supplied by the inner generator if the client didn’t always know when the execution was finished.)

Comment: Makes sense! Thank you.